# RNA-seq gene/transcript read counts database for Mouse

Tags: rna-seq, reads, data-mining

Is there any RNAseq gene/transcript read count database for the mouse? I already know about [ARCHS4](https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/archs4/), looking for some other source.

Thank you

Comment: You can sometimes get counts from GEO, though that's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EBI has an expression atlas, including mouse: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/experiments?species=mus+musculus

If you click on one of the individual experiments you can download tables of TPM or RPKM per gene.

There are currently about 1000 individual experiments in different tissues etc.